# How to use Join in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two tables: `product, product_names`

```
Product   Product_names
id        id | name | language | objectId
```

I use function `names()` in Model that connects these both table by `key: id = objectId`

When I do request like as:

```
$arr = Product::with("names")->get();
```

I get collection with object from table `Product` and separated coolection with `names()`

How can I merger this in one collection result?

So, I need to get something as:

```
$oneResultObject = SELECT Product_names.name AS name from Product LEFT JOIN Product_names ON Product_names.objectId = Product.id;
```

Without using `::with("Product_names")`

Answer (score 0):

For example:

product.php model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    function productNames() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\ProductName', 'id', 'objectId');
    }

    public function show($id){
         self::with('productNames')->where('id', $id)->get();
    }
}
```

in ProductController.php

```
 public function viewProduct($id, Product $products)
    {
        $product = $products->show($id);
        return view('product', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

in product.blade.php

```
<table>
<tbody>
@foreach ($products as $product)
<tr>
<th>{{ $product->id }}</th>
<td>{{ $product->productNames->name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: From where did you get `Post`?

Comment: Why I can not use simple:  `$subcategories = Product::with("productNames")->get();` ?

Comment: Post this is a mistake, corrected. I wrote all the details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = DB::table('product')
        ->leftJoin('product_names', 'product.id', '=', 'product_names.objectId ')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Laravel's Query Builder (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins)

For your question, here it is:

```
$prodcuts = DB::table('product')
       ->leftJoin('product_names', 'product.id', '=', 'product_names.objectId ')
       ->get();
```